# How to send emails directly from Common Lisp?

Tags: email, smtp, common-lisp

I was wondering if there is an easy but secure way to send emails via an external smtp server with some status information directly from my CL code. I have checked [CLiki](https://www.cliki.net/email) and there are several solutions, in principle. I would like to have a pure CL solution without any external infrastructure installed on my system or storing passwords in my source code.

Are there any recommendation before I start to test the different libraries?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by “smtp client”? I think there’s a bunch of different email specific terminology about mail user agents and mail transfer agents and so on. And I don’t think I understand what “secure” means in this context. My prior is that email is basically insecure with a bunch of extra attempts at security tracked on in complicated ways. I doubt I’ll know the answer to this question. Also be warned that library recommendations are generally out of scope for stack overflow.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I meant a solution which doesn‘t depend on further software installed on my system like sendmail and works with an external smtp server. Sorry for mixing up client/server.

Answer (score 1):

I set up email sending recently in an app of mine and I went with SendGrid's API.

I came up with [cl-sendgrid](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-sendgrid). The core of it is sending a JSON object via a POST request.

> a pure CL solution without any external infrastructure installed on my system or storing passwords in my source code.

Let's say it's a pure CL solution since the library only does a POST to SendGrid's API…

There is also [a wrapper for Mailgun](https://github.com/40ants/mailgun).

ps: there is a pre-selection of libraries here: https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#email but maybe is it not exhaustive, feel free to send edits.

Comment: Thanks, as I just need to send very few emails through my personal email account I will try [cl-smtp](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/cl-smtp/cl-smtp). I just have to get the authentication right...